# Регулярное выражение не берет текст

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть регулярное выражение без (?:) выделяет все предложения, но как хочу выделить группу, то первые 2 даже не видит.
Примеры предложений:
Генеральный директор В. В. Вас
Должность Генеральный директор
Ф.И.О. Васил В.В.
Руководитель (должность, ФИО) Васил Василий Васильевич
Директор - -Васил Василий Васильевич Коммерческий директор – Васил Василий Васильевич

```
[Гг]енеральный.[Дд]иректор.+|[Гг]енеральный.[Дд]иректор\n.+|[Рр]уководитель.*|^[Дд]иректор[\s\S].+|Директор .*?[А-Я].*?[А-Я].*?[А-Я].*?|Директор.([А-ЯЁ][а-яё]*(?:-[А-ЯЁ][а-яё]*)? [А-ЯЁ][а-яё]*(?:-[А-ЯЁ][а-яё]*)? [А-ЯЁ][а-яё]*(?:-[А-ЯЁ][а-яё]*)?)
```

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/GJ9dl5/1)

```
(?:[Гг]енеральный.[Дд]иректор.+|[Гг]енеральный.[Дд]иректор\n.+|[Рр]уководитель.*|^[Дд]иректор[\s\S].+|Директор .*?[А-Я].*?[А-Я].*?[А-Я].*?|Директор.)([А-ЯЁ][а-яё]*(?:-[А-ЯЁ][а-яё]*)? [А-ЯЁ][а-яё]*(?:-[А-ЯЁ][а-яё]*)? [А-ЯЁ][а-яё]*(?:-[А-ЯЁ][а-яё]*)?)
```

Comment: Так https://regex101.com/r/GJ9dl5/2?

Comment: Благодарю, спасибо) я решил проблему, но более криво у вас лучше